# Como clicar em um item da ListView e abrir uma Activity referênte ao item que cliquei?

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma listView que tem como conteúdo uma lista com nome de países gravado no banco(SQLite). Eu precisava clicar por exemplo no Item Brasil, e abrir outra ListView com os estados do Brasil, já fiz isso sem banco de dados, porém com banco não estou conseguindo porque preciso puxar do banco e não do objeto, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Comment: Quando você clica em um item da `ListView` ele pega a `position`, porquê não pega o Nome Brasil e faz uma pesquisa no banco para preencher seu objeto novamente?

Comment: @daniel12345smith, por favor, adicione o código de como você está preenchendo essa `ListView` vai ajudar muito fazendo isso.

Answer (score 1):

Existem inúmeras formas de atingir este objetivo. Vou sugerir um approach que considero eficiente.

O ideal seria implementar sua própria versão do ** SimpleCursorAdapter**, registrar um callback responsável por executar a ação desejada e repassar para este callback algum dado referente ao seu registro, preferencialmente um ID.

No seu callback você executa a operação utilizando a referência recebida, no caso abrir uma nova activity. Receba a referência na activity e faça uma nova consulta ao DB com a referência.

1 - Tutorial para implementar [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://pt.androids.help/q8461)

2 - Implemente uma interface em seu adapter para repassar a info ao seu callback

```
public interface MyListener {
    void setOnClickAdapter(final View view, final int myId );
}
```

3 - Registre seu listener no método **bindView** de seu adapter

```
@Override
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
   //....
   MyListener listener = (TaskListener)context;
   listener.setOnClickAdapter( myTextView, id );
```

4 - Em sua activity utilizada como context implemente a interface do adapter

```
@Override
public void setOnClickAdapter( final View view, final int id)
{
   view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener )
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Execute sua operação
        }
}
```